# asp.net forms authentication showing same LastActivityDate for all users

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication

I'm not sure why this is happening, but the last activity date for all my users is showing the same. I thought it was the way I was pulling the data from the database, but I checked my data, and it shows the same for all users.

Is there something I need to be doing to get this field updated? I'm not doing anything special with this field other than reporting it.

Comment: What is the LastActivityDate? something recent, or from whenever you set up the database?

Comment: It's 9/30/2011 11:00:34 PM.  I deployed the site on 9/30/2011 at 9am or so.  I don't know what happened at 11pm, but I doubt the there was anyone active in the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer here in [this article](http://leedumond.com/blog/how-to-prevent-profile-properties-from-updating-a-users-last-activity-date/).  Apparently, when I pull up the list of users and I pull the profile for each, it calls a stored procedure that in turn, updates the LastActivityDate of each user to the current date and time.